# Coefficients in $\pm 1$

Tags: inequality

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ be positive reals. Show that there are numbers $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n \in \{-1,1\}$ such that the following holds:
$$\displaystyle a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2+\cdots+a_nx_n^2 \ge (a_1x_1+a_2x_2 +\cdots+a_nx_n)^2$$

This is an olympiad problem but I don't know how to do it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Seems like an Arithmetic-Geometric inequality type problem.

Comment: Really? I thought about Cauchy-Schwartz but I would love to know your solution. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if I misled you, I was being sort-of temptative, but let me see if I can come up with something substantial.

Comment: This is (almost) [Jensen's inequality][1] 
$$ \varphi\left( \sum_i a_i x_i \right) \leq \sum_i a_i \varphi(x_i) $$
with $\varphi(x_i) = x_i^2$.  It is not quite Jensen's inequality in that it does not meet the hypotheses that $\sum_i a_i = 1$ and $a_i \geq 0$.

  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Alternative_finite_form

Answer (score 0):

Hint: without loss of generality assume that the $x_j$ are arranged in nonascending order: $x_1\ge x_2\ge\dots$. Then take $a_j=(-1)^{j-1}$.

Comment: How is that working? The inequality becomes :
$(x_1^2-x_2^2+\ldots )\ge (x_1-x_2+\ldots)^2$ how to prove this? Expanding is going to be confusing I think, can you prove it completely? @Vladimir

Comment: In the proof that was just edited away, the signs assigned to the $x_i$ oscillate with every increment of $j$.  Consider the sign of $x_n$ in your sums $b_j$ and $c_j$ when $j=n$ versus $j=n-1$.